# Prove that $AB=DA+BC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

another problem  from a book

$ABCD$ convex quadrilateral,$C(O,r)$ circle such that $O\in [AB]$ and touched $BC,DC,DA$ in $E,F,N$ respectively

Prove that when a quadrilateral is to be drawn within a circle, then

> $$AB=DA+BC$$

solution: 
let $E,F,N$ touched circle in $BC,DC,DA$ respectively

then : $EB=r\cot B,AN=r\cot A,EC=r\cot (\frac{C}{2})=r\tan (\frac{A}{2}),ND=r\cot (\frac{D}{2})=r\tan (\frac{B}{2})$ 
then 
$AD+BC=r(\cot A+\cot B+\tan (\frac{A}{2})+\tan (\frac{B}{2})=r(\frac{1}{\sin A}+\frac{1}{\sin B})=AB$

note that : 
$OB=\frac{r}{\sin B},OA=\frac{1}{\sin A}$ 
I don't understand this solution actually for me new relations ? 
can someone explain to me ?

Comment: "another problem from a book" is not informative.

Comment: Out of the last 11 questions you have asked which have received answers, you have not accepted a single answer. Why not? There are two reasons for accepting answers: (1) to reward person doing the work, (2) to stop the question cluttering up the unanswered list.

Comment: Most of the proof involves relationships in right angled triangles. Please can you be more specific about which you are happy with and which not?

Answer (score 1):

The crucial part of this proof concerns the fact that $$\cot A+\cot B+\tan (\frac{A}{2})+\tan (\frac{B}{2})=\frac{1}{\sin A}+\frac{1}{\sin B}.$$

This follows since 
$$\cot A+\tan (\frac{A}{2})=\frac{1-2(\sin A/2)^2}{\sin A}+ \frac{(2\sin A/2)^2}{\sin A}  =\frac{1}{\sin A}$$
with the identical result for $B$.